# How to reroute a resource to include a different field besides $id in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a resource controlling one of my tables "fans".  I have a view that shows the information for each respective.  The urls for these right now is "url.com/fans/{$id}", where {$id} is the unique id for the row/object in the table.

I would like to maintain this relationship, but I would also like to the url be pointed to another column in the table (another unique identifier).  So something like "ulr.com/fans/{$new_column}".

How would I reroute this view/url so that it appears like that?  This is what I have so far:

Routes:

```
Route::resource('fans', 'FansController');
```

FansController:

```
public function show($id) {

$fan = Fan::find($id);
return View::make('fans.show', compact('fan'));

}
```

So ultimately, I would like "url.com/fans/{$id}" to still work, but then it will be rerouted to "url.com/fans/{$new_column}".  And going directly to "url.com/fans/{$new_column} should just stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to differentiate between each parameter value between *id* and *new_column* you can declare all your routes for *fans* route with *Route::get* instead of *Route::resource* and define **Regular Expression Route Constraints**, so for example if your *id* column has numbers only and your *new_column* column has alpha values:

```
Route::get('fans/{new_column}', array('as' => 'anotherColumn', function($new_column)
{
    $fan = Fan::where('new_column','=',$new_column);
    return View::make('fans.show', compact('fan'));
}))
->where('new_column', '[A-Za-z]+');

Route::get('fans/{id}', function($id)
{
    // do something with $id or
    return Redirect::route('anotherColumn');
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Then declare the rest of the automatically generated resource routes.

Comment: Would I have to then declare each individual route for the remainder of the resource as well?  index, create, edit, etc...

Comment: Yes, all of them to have the same routes managed by the resource type.

Comment: Can you please explain what the "where('new_column', '[A-Za-z]+');" portion does?  What is the "new_column" has letters and numbers in it (and underscores)

Comment: You have to differentiate id and new_column with a regex, or it won't be possible to select to which route it will get matched.

Comment: When I try to run this, I get the error: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("new_column") to generate a URL for route "anotherColumn".  Even though I have this column in place, and have a value in it for the page I am trying to view.