# How do I create a URL in Laravel that doesn't reveal the resource ID?

Tags: laravel-4

As I'm developing my app I realized I don't want end users seeing resource IDs in the URL.

Consider the URL `http://localhost/users/12345` which is the logical way to GET the desired user resource.

What is the best way around this?

Here is a related question: [How to reroute a resource to include a different field besides $id in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210276/how-to-reroute-a-resource-to-include-a-different-field-besides-id-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Why do you not want to reveal the resource ID if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I'd like to protect my user resource IDs in particular

Answer (score 2):

Convert your ID to something else. Take the Tiny-PHP package for example: https://github.com/zackkitzmiller/tiny-php, you can use it to:

```
URL::route('user', array('user_id' => $tiny->to($user->id)));
```

And when you get it back:

```
$user = User::find($tiny->from(Input::get('user_id')));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best choiche you'll end up with is [Hashids](http://www.hashids.org/). It basically takes any number and spit out an (apparently) random string, based on a encoding key you provide. You will then have urls like Youtube videos or bit.ly links, without exposing your resources IDs. You can start using it directly in Laravel including [this repository](https://github.com/mrynk/l4-hashids) in your composer.json file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use another unique identifier such as a username and within the route you can do something like this...

```
Route::get('user/{username}', array('uses' => 'Username@show', 'as' => 'username'));
```

The '{username}' part is a wildcard to say that any username within the database can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this possible solution for votes. Would making a reference to `username` instead of `id` and making that a `unique` field suffice?